# Digital signatures in pdf

Tags: node.js, pdf, digital-signature, pkcs#7, google-cloud-kms

I'm trying to digitally sign a pdf file using a [PKCS#7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS) formatted signature in NodeJS.

**The setup:**

[Node-forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge#pkcs7) does a great job at generating PKCS#7 format. I've already validated that the end output of the library fits my needs. By default pkcs7 requires an input of:

1. Certificate that includes signer's public key
2. Binary content to be signed
3. Signer's private key

**The problem:**

I want to generate and store my signer (user) keys in [HSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module) so the private key is not directly accessible to me. So instead of content to be signed (2.) and signer's private key (3.) I can provide the end result - the signed content as input. I haven't been able to find an option to do so in node-forge, or any other javascript library.

For reference [openssl](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/PKCS7_sign.html) command requires the same 3 parameters.

I've found a solution for java, using the bouncycastle library. It gives the ability to implement [ContentSigner](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/operator/ContentSigner.html) interface. You can basically tell the library - "get the signature from here whenever you sign a file", so in theory it should be possible to create PKCS#7 with only certificate(s) and signed content.

**The question:**

How can I generate PKCS#7, or any other valid PDF signature format, by using only certificate and the signed file content?

Comment: Please provide more information in reference to your tag for Google-cloud-kms. Are you looking for solution  to apply the default pkcs7 with GCP KMS/HSM  for your pdf file ?

Comment: Yes, I am using the nodejs-kms client library to [create a signature](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-kms/blob/master/samples/signAsymmetric.js). I want to apply that signature to pkcs7 signed data format, which will later be embedded in my pdf file.

Comment: Have you used the Google supported document on the [digital signature](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/digital-signatures) and [Creating and validating digital signatures](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/create-validate-signatures#validate_rsa_signature) ? Have you observed error while applying that signature to pkcs7 signed data format ? Can you please provide me more information and the screenshots of any error message ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using kms through the client library for nodejs. I'm creating a digital signature with [signAsymmetric](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-kms/blob/master/samples/signAsymmetric.js) function. The problem is that I can't put that signed data directly into the pdf. According to pdf spec I need to embed it into PKCS#7 format first and I'm not sure exactly how to do that.